# How do I create an alternate RSS feed for tags with custom image sizes for MailChimp?

Tags: images, rss, plugin-mailchimp

I am looking to create an alternate RSS feed for a specific group of tags with custom image sizes to be used with MailChimp.

Is it possible to customize RSS feeds for specific tags? For example the tag "Apple" we would like the feed to have an image size of 100x100 in the RSS feed, whereas for the tag "Orange" we would like the images to be of size 500x500? We're using this for a MailChimp RSS newsletter and MailChimp can only pickup the first image within the feed so we need the sizing to be done on a per-tag basis and on the feed-level rather within the HTML/CSS.

Answer (score 1):

Filter `'the_content_feed'` or `'the_excerpt_rss'` and use a thumbnail image of your choice.

Sample code, not tested:

```
add_filter( 'the_content_feed', 'wpse_70249_custom_thumb' );
add_filter( 'the_excerpt_rss', 'wpse_70249_custom_thumb' );

function wpse_70249_custom_thumb( $content )
{
    global $post;

    $thumb_size = 'post-thumbnail';

    if ( in_category( 'orange', $post )
    {
        $thumb_size = array ( 500, 500 );
    }
    if ( in_category( 'apple', $post )
    {
        $thumb_size = array ( 100, 100 );
    }

    $thumb = get_the_post_thumbnail( null, $thumb_size );

    return $thumb . $content;
}
```